# Rails association= return value and behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

The guide does not say what return value would be for `association=` methods. For example the [`has_one association=`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#methods-added-by-has-one-association-associate)

For the simple case, it returns the assigned object. However this is only when assignment succeeds.

Sometimes `association=` would persist the change in database immediately, for example a persisted record setting the has_one association.

- How does `association=` react to assignment failure? (Can I tell if it fails?)
- Is there a bang! version in which failure raises exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference-when-are-objects-saved-questionmark

So another part of the guide does talk about the return behavior for association assignment.

If association assignment fails, it returns false.
There is no bang version of this.

### Update

Behaviors around :has_many/has_one through seems to be different.

Demo repository: https://github.com/lulalalalistia/association-assignment-demo

In the demo I seeded some data in first commit, and hard code validation error in second commit. Demo is using rails 4.2

#### has_many through

```
class Boss < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :room_ownerships, as: :owner
  has_many :rooms, through: :room_ownerships
end
```

When I add a room, exception is raised:

```
irb(main):008:0> b.rooms << Room.first
  Boss Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "bosses".* FROM "bosses"  ORDER BY "bosses"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Room Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms"  ORDER BY "rooms"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: foo
irb(main):014:0> b.rooms
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

#### has_one through

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :room_ownership, as: :owner
  has_one :room, through: :room_ownership
end
```

When I add a room I don't get exception:

```
irb(main):021:0> e.room = Room.first
  Room Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "rooms".* FROM "rooms"  ORDER BY "rooms"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  RoomOwnership Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "room_ownerships".* FROM "room_ownerships" WHERE "room_ownerships"."owner_id" = ? AND "room_ownerships"."owner_type" = ? LIMIT 1  [["owner_id", 1], ["owner_type", "Employee"]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
=> #<Room id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-03 02:32:33", updated_at: "2016-10-03 02:32:33">
irb(main):022:0> e.room
=> #<Room id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-03 02:32:33", updated_at: "2016-10-03 02:32:33">
```

This makes it difficult to see whether the assignment succeeds or not.

Answer (score 1):

> How does association= react to assignment failure? (Can I tell if it fails?)

It can't fail. Whatever you assign, it will either work as expected:

> Behind the scenes, this means extracting the primary key from this
>   object and setting the associated object's foreign key to the same
>   value.

or will save the association as a string representation of passed in object, if the object is "invalid".

> Is there a bang! version in which failure raises exception?

Nope, there is not.

Answer (score 0):

The `association=` should not be able to fail. It is a simple assignment to a attribute on your attribute. There are no validations called by this method and the connection doesn't get persisted in the database until you call `save`.

The return value of assignments is the value you pass to it.

Comment: In some cases, association= would persist immediately, for example a persisted has_one changing an association. So I was wondering if this can fail.

Comment: I don't know of a situation where `association=` would change anything persisted, unless you're doing something tricky. You need to `save` before anything is persisted. There are other operations, e.g. `<<`, which *do* immediately have persisted effects, but setter methods do not do this -- if I'm wrong please give a concrete counter example.